# SAPUI5 create library

Tags: sapui5

I would like to create a new library in SAPUI5 and use declare

```
jQuery.sap.declare("app.util.Test", true);

var Test = {
    myFn: function(){return 'foo'}
}
```

But when I want to use it, it is not found

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "app/util/Test"
], function(Controller, Test) {
"use strict";

    return Controller.extend("app.controller.MyTest", {
        onInit: function() {
            // Test undefined
            var baa = Test.myFn();
        }
    });
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you have written that code. More specifically, whether or not is was execute before the `sap.ui.define` call of the Controller or if it is indeed located in the correct path.

Assuming that your *root* namespace is `app`, your folder structure should look like this:

```
rootFolder
|-controller
|---MyTest.controller.js
|-util
|---Test.js
```

Also, you are not doing anything with the `Test` object. `jQuery.sap.define` simply creates a global object and registers it against the UI5 registry. It does not correlate your `Test` object with this global object. So you should do:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("app.util.Test", true);

app.util.Test = {
    myFn: function(){return 'foo'}
}
```

Normally, you should not use [jQuery.sap.declare](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.declare) but simply use [sap.ui.define](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define) for the *utility module* as well (to avoid global variable usage). You don't have to specify the module name if your folder structure is correct (as the framework will deduce it from the file's location).

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    return {
        myFn: function(){return 'foo'}
    };
});
```

Just wanted to point out that you are **not** defining a library, but simply a utility module. You can check out the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bd039ed5f99e4d3f8d020b0da62f9d85.html) about creating a new UI5 library (which normally is used to group custom controls, elements and so on).